# Separar dataframe en base a una fecha, para luego obtener la suma de las columnas

Tags: python, base-de-datos, pandas

#### Datos

```
start_date    end_date    very    somewhat    not_very    
2020-03-02    2020-03-17   19      26          33    
2020-03-02    2020-03-24    20      20          35    
2020-03-09    2020-04-10    22       8          41    
2020-04-10    2020-04-28    41      11          24     
2020-04-14    2020-05-01    60      12          18
```

#### Quiero:

Calcular la suma de las columnas `very`, `somewhat` y `not_very`, **para antes y después de una fecha determinada** (ej. 2020-03-09).

#### Dudas

- He visto como dividir el dataframe en dos, pero no tengo claro que sea necesario tener que trabajar con dos dataframes.
- Creo que una solución más acertada sería iterar el dataframe, pero: (1) no tengo claro como hacerlo (2) no sé si sería más eficiente o no.
- Si posteriormente quiero representar los resultados gráficamente, ¿la solución anterior podría complicar innecesariamente el ejercicio?

¿Alguna idea de como proceder?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta me pareció buena, pero como consejo céntrate en algo especifico, al hacer varias preguntas se puede reportar como *necesita ser más especifica*

Comment: Osea quieres operar con los datos, pero excluyendo a la fecha de inicio (ej 2020-03-09)??

Comment: @Christian quiero calcular la suma de las columnas very, somewhat y not_very para antes y después de una fecha determinada.

Comment: Haaa ya, utiliza un *filtro*, ahora no puedo dar una respuesta pues estoy en celular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dije en mi comentario, se puede usar un *filtro* para obtener esos datos , pero de igual forma se obtiene un *Dataframe*, pues si operamos con *Dataframes* el resultado será un *Dataframe*, es igual que con los números, si operamos con números, el resultado será un numero.

Si quieres iterar en el DF no hay ningún problema, solo será mas lento el proceso y hay funciones de pandas que nos permiten obtener el mismo resultado.

Bueno para hacer el *filtro* solo basta con especificar la columna y la condición, sea mayor o menor a un dato

```py
mayor_inicio = df[df["start_date"]>"2020-03-09"].sum()
```

Y para los datos menores

```py
menor_inicio = df[df["start_date"]<"2020-03-09"].sum()
```

Se agrega el `.sum()` para sumar los valores, también puedes sumar una columna específica haciendo

```py
menor_inicio = df[df["start_date"]<"2020-03-09"]["very"].sum()
```

Ambas variables son de tipo *Dataframe* , pandas trae una función para hacer un gráfico, pero no creo que sea correcto explicarlo pues la pregunta se sale mucho del tema original.

Comment: va el +1 cuando agregues el  `.sum` :-p

Comment: Me había olvidado, gracias :D